# Cursor doesn't iterate through all Database Table

Tags: android, listview, cursor

I Wrote a Cursor that will read inside the databasehelper class all the information from the table, and assigned it a custom listview where I want each element to corresponding field. However the Cursor is printing last element only alongside with constricted with how 3 iterations only.

Here is the Database Helper Class:

```
public Cursor getPrograss(){
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase ();
StatsitcsHelper object = new StatsitcsHelper ();

Cursor cursor =  db.rawQuery ("select * from " + TABLE_PROGGRES, null);

cursor.moveToFirst();
if (cursor!= null && cursor.getCount() > 0 &&  !cursor.isAfterLast()){

    cursor.moveToNext();
}
return cursor;
```

}
And here is the Fragment Function calling it :

```
    public void ShowStatstics() {

    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper (getActivity ());
    Cursor cursor =  db.getPrograss ();


    String DataA = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_P_Date));
    String WeightA =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_P_Weight));
    String PercentA = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_P_Percentage));



    String[] Prograss = {DataA,WeightA,PercentA};

    ListAdapter listAdapter = new StatisticsAdapter (getActivity (),Prograss);
    lest.setAdapter (listAdapter);
}
```

Here is the Adapter:

```
class StatisticsAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
public StatisticsAdapter(@NonNull Context context, String[] resource) {
    super (context, R.layout.listview_layout ,resource);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater ListInflate = LayoutInflater.from(getContext ());

    StatsitcsHelper statsitcsHelper = new StatsitcsHelper ();
    View customView = ListInflate.inflate (R.layout.listview_layout,parent,false);

    String first = getItem (0);
    TextView date = (TextView) customView.findViewById (R.id.List_Date);

    String Second = getItem (1);
    TextView Weight = (TextView) customView.findViewById (R.id.List_Weight);

    String Thierd = getItem (2);
    TextView Percent = (TextView) customView.findViewById (R.id.List_Percentage);

    date.setText (first);
    Weight.setText (Second);
    Percent.setText (Thierd);

    return customView;

}
 }
```

Comment: You want to get list of rows or columns..?

Comment: I have three Variables each row "Date", "Weight","Percentage". i want them inside a custom listView which i made. with three columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a POJO class like this,

```
public class Data {
    String date;
    String weight;
    String percentage;
}
```

then in your method you can return ArrayList and show in a list like below,

```
public ArrayList<Data> getPrograss() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    StatsitcsHelper object = new StatsitcsHelper();

    Cursor cursor =  db.rawQuery ("select * from " + TABLE_PROGGRES, null);

    ArrayList<Data> datas = new ArrayList<>();

    if(cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {

            cursor.moveToPosition(i);

            Data data = new Data();
            data.date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_P_Date));
            data.weight = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_P_Weight));
            data.percentage = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_P_Percentage));

            datas.add(data);
        }

        cursor.close();
    }

    return datas;
}
```

You Adapter class look like this,

```
class StatisticsAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<Data> {
    public StatisticsAdapter(@NonNull Context context, ArrayList<Data> resource) {
        super (context, R.layout.listview_layout ,resource);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater ListInflate = LayoutInflater.from(getContext ());

        Data data = getItem(position);

        View customView = ListInflate.inflate (R.layout.listview_layout,parent,false);

        String first = data.date;
        TextView date = (TextView) customView.findViewById (R.id.List_Date);

        String Second = data.weight;
        TextView Weight = (TextView) customView.findViewById (R.id.List_Weight);

        String Thierd = data.percentage;
        TextView Percent = (TextView) customView.findViewById (R.id.List_Percentage);

        date.setText (first);
        Weight.setText (Second);
        Percent.setText (Thierd);

        return customView;

    }
}
```

you can create the adapter from your method like this,

```
public void showStatstics() {
    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper (getActivity ());
    ArrayList<Data> datas =  db.getPrograss ();

    ListAdapter listAdapter = new StatisticsAdapter (getActivity (),datas);
    lest.setAdapter (listAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Awsome Muthukrishnan Rajendran, and how i would call it  inside ShowStatstics().

Comment: could you please add your ShowStatstics adapter in question..?

Comment: Updated Muthukrishnan Rajendran

Comment: Updated my answer have a look

Comment: Ok it printed many repeated item, However its all the First Row it didn't jump to the next row.

Comment: I Added cursor.moveToNext (); and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I missed cursor.moveToPosition(i); in for loop i added have a look

Comment: Muthukrishnan Rajendran I Have to Thank you, This is very efficient code and solved my problem completely..